# DDNS SSH Connection to OSMC r-pi not working

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running OSMC and have set up DDNS through http://freedns.afraid.org. I am able to SSH on my local network, and ping the domain I have set from outside the network. However, I am unable to connect via SSH. I have port fowarded on my router (Linksys EA8300, I have xfinity as my ISP).

The Raspberry Pi is also running open vpn using ExpressVPN, I set up the domain using the external IP of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Have you configured your router to forward port 22 to the pi?

Comment: yeah, I have forward 22 to a nonstandard external port, also 9091 as I have transmission set up for that port, neither work outside my network using the domain I have

Comment: If you set up DDNS and your router correctly, there should at least be some log entries: Please check `journalctl -u ssh.service`. If there are none, check that DDNS works properly: `dig *yourDomain*`